# Archive a trello board/list (API)

Tags: trello

I would like to archive a board/list with the trello API but I can't find a solution.

With https://trello.com/docs/api/list/#post-1-lists-idlist-archiveallcards I can archive all cards inside a list but I can't archive the list itself.

For boards I didn't find anything.
But deleting cards are easy with https://trello.com/docs/api/card/#delete-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink
Any ideas or isn't it possible with the API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The card delete method you've linked to is a full deletion - unlike archiving, the card is irrevocably gone.

You're looking for the `closed` property, which can be set on boards, lists, and cards (true to archive, false to unarchive).  If you archive all cards inside a list, you'll see that setting closed to true on each of those cards is the only change being made.

Comment: That is a little bit confusing for new users of Trello. In their UI, all you see is the term "Archive" and then, once Archived, you would see the "Delete" option. I couldn't find the word "closed" anywhere.

Comment: @TheBrockEllis That's because we used to call the option `closed`, but we avoid changing the API so as to not break older API consumers.  We're working on getting info like that into our API documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Aaron! I know the pains of making things backwards compatible. It's a very powerful API but just a little hard to follow sometimes. Glad to hear that the docs are getting some more information added to them. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

the property `closed` is *BEFORE*  the `?` in the documentation,  making it look like  a path parameter,  when it is actually a boolean query parameter